# Can't find "separate" menu in object mode

Tags: modeling, interface

I'm beginner using Blender 2.91.0.
I'm following tutorials and I tried to search "separate" but nothing shows up in obejcet mode.

[image]

+Thanks for answer and comments.

I was following this tutorial: youtube.com/watch?v=At9qW8ivJ4Q.
I found out that separate is only possible in edit mode before asking this question. However on the video at at 1:00:54, it seems that Separate is possible in object mode. Mine still didn't work in object mode, so I was curious about it.

Comment: by separate you mean separate a mesh from object? the shortcut is P, but you need to be in Edit mode

Comment: Please refer to the first comment of the linked video to get your answer : " Well, previously separate options used to be available on object mode as well. But now if you want to separate objects, then you need to go to edit mode and then search separate in your search menu or access it from the menu or you can use hotkey 'P'.  Also, keep in mind there are 3 options in separate   1. selection 2. Material 3 Loose Parts.  So if you need to separate via selection then you need to be in edit mode. If you want to separate using loose parts then you can do that on object mode as well. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be done in **Edit** mode.

Select the object.

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode*

Select the geometry you'd like to split up, press <kbd>P</kbd> which opens up the [*Separate* menu](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/separate.html) and choose "Selection".

If you got multiple loose disconnected parts as one object, you can simply choose "By Loose Parts" to split them up into individual objects at once.

Or you can use the menu: ***Mesh*** > ***Separate*** >

[image]

Further reading: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/separate.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=At9qW8ivJ4Q
at 1:00:54, It seems that Separate is possible in object mode. Could you get a look at it?

Comment: @Mins the action he does in the video is equivalent to clicking P and choosing loose parts so ya logically its possible to do it in object mode also